# How to reason about sequences of composable arrows in a category?

Tags: logic, reference-request, category-theory

Suppose I am given a (small) category $\mathcal{C}$.
I would like to have a panoramic idea about what structure is enjoyed by the sequences of composable arrows of $\mathcal{C}$.
I heard about the nerve construction, showing that sequences of composable arrows arrange in a simplicial complex, giving a topological model of the category.
This is really nice but for my aims I would like to know if we can have sequences of composable encoded (as objects or morphism or otherwise) in another category $\mathsf{Seq}(\mathcal{C})$, in order to have a kind of semantical place to talk about them. Moreover I would like to consider possibly infinite composition sequences.
In particular, I am interested in sequences of composable arrows in $\mathsf{FinOrd}$ thought as the skeleton of $\mathsf{FinSet}$.
What I thought is to consider the presheaf category:
$$[\mathbb{N}^{op}\to\mathsf{FinSet}]$$
Anyhow the data here is somehow plenoastic for the application I have in mind: I do not really need all the arrows $n\leq m$ but only the local data given $n\leq n+1$ (in a sense I care about composable sequences, but not about the act of compositions).
Sadly I do not have a really comprehensive knowledge of category theory, but I suspect some construction like this exists.

Comment: Ok, you want to consider the sequences of composable arrows as the objects of a category. What should be the arrows of this category? In particular, what should be an arrow between sequences of different lengths?

Comment: I don't know, that's the point: maybe I expressed badly my question. I was wondering if there exists some known construction to study the composable sequnce in a category, apart from the nerve construnction

Comment: I do not really get the reason for the -1

Comment: I did not downvote. I suspect the downvoter found the question too imprecise or speculative.

Comment: Yes, I thought  it wasn't you! I dropped  a comment just for the sake of it

Comment: At the same time, I asked the question in the following Zulip chat on CT, I paste the link in case some future user is interested https://categorytheory.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/229199-learning.3A-questions